# Safari removes fragment identifiers when hyperlink is clicked (perhaps .htaccess issue?)

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

In my recent web design project, I used [a fairly solid technique](http://www.niallflynn.com/seo-news/remove-file-extension-from-urls/) to remove .php file extensions from pages on the website. However, in Safari only, this method now also removes fragment identifiers when a user clicks on the hyperlink from another page. This results in someone going to .com/example instead of .com/example#fradmentidentifier. Here's my .htaccess code:

```
AddType text/x-component .htc
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# remove .php; use THE_REQUEST to prevent infinite loops
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ (.*)\.php\ HTTP
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ $1 [R=301]
# remove index
RewriteRule (.*)/index$ $1/ [R=301]
# remove slash if not directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
RewriteRule (.*)/ $1 [R=301]
# add .php to access file, but don't redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]
```

Example can be seen at [this site](http://www.dentistwoodburymn.com) in the sidebar list titled "Creating Healthy & Beautiful Smiles."

I might be mistaken, but I don't remember running into this problem before. Know of a fix?

Comment: What do you mean by *anchor extensions*? The part of the URL, that follows the `#`?. This part is called the *fragment identifier*. The fragment identifier is never sent to the server when making a request, so your `.htaccess` is not the cause of your problem.

Comment: Thank you for calling me out on the terminology, @Oswald. Yes, indeed I meant the fragment identifier. Question updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that example site http://www.dentistwoodburymn.com/ the page you are working on?

If so, then why are you still using the `.php` extension in the links you set there – didn’t you say you wanted to *remove* that extension (and therefor you have that rewriting in place, so that a request for `/foo` gets rewritten to `/foo.php` *internally* automatically) …?

Replace this kind of link

```
<a href="avi-matha-dds.php#more-about">
```

with

```
<a href="avi-matha-dds#more-about">
```

– and the server-side rewriting takes care of pointing that to the file `avi-matha-dds.php` *internally* … and your Safari problem, which only happens *because of your external redirect* of `.php` to the non-`.php` version that you are issuing here

```
# remove .php; use THE_REQUEST to prevent infinite loops
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ (.*)\.php\ HTTP
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ $1 [R=301]
```

… will be gone as well.

Comment: That's exactly the issue I created myself and should have caught. When first designing the site, I host it under a shared account, so at that point the .php was needed. In other words, a silly oversight on my part and wonderfully explained by you, @CBroe. Thank you.